# "/bin/sh 'ls -l -R'" vs "/bin/sh -c 'ls -l -R'"

Tags: unix, shell, ksh, aix

What is the difference between the following two commands, when run on AIX?

```
/bin/sh 'ls -l -R'
/bin/sh -c 'ls -l -R'
```

Comment: The second one passes an additional parameter. :P

Comment: What do you mean? What additional parameter?

Comment: Among bash, dash, busybox ash, zsh, csh, rc and ksh on my system, only ksh works without the `-c`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On AIX, `/bin/sh` defaults to the Korn Shell (ksh).

```
/bin/sh 'ls -l -R'
```

With ksh, this runs the shell, telling it to execute the script named `ls -l -R` (in the current directory or on the path). If no script can be found with this name, ksh treats the argument as a command and runs it.

Note that with bash, if the script cannot be found, this would result in an error.

```
/bin/sh -c 'ls -l -R'
```

This starts a new instance of the shell, telling it to run the command `ls -l -R`.

Comment: >/bin/sh 'ls -l -R'  
total 80  
-rw-rw----   1 user    user         39301 Mar 22 18:17 db.trace

Comment: I do not have any problems with the command /bin/sh 'ls -l -R'

Comment: @Vladimir: Then you have different version of sh. On my system, the above command results in: `/bin/sh: Can't open ls -l -R`. What does `ls -l /bin/sh` show on your system?

Comment: >ls -l /bin/sh
-r-xr-xr-x   5 bin      bin          246558 Sep 20 2008  /bin/sh

Comment: @Vladimir What is the result of running `/bin/sh --version`?

Comment: $ /bin/sh --version
--version: bad option(s)

Comment: @Vladimir Since, you are using AIX, `sh` is probably the Korn shell (ksh). I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

*(This is in response to Phil Ross, but I need formatting:)*

Using one of my Linux accounts:

```
sh> /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
sh>  /bin/sh 'ls -l -R'
/bin/sh: ls -l -R: No such file or directory
sh> /bin/sh ls
/bin/ls: /bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
sh> /bin/sh -c 'ls -l | head -1'
total 147296
sh>
```

Using one of my Cygwin installations:

```
sh> /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.49(23)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
sh> /bin/sh 'ls -l -R'
/bin/sh: ls -l -R: No such file or directory
sh> /bin/sh ls
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
sh> /bin/sh -c 'ls -l | head -1'
total 264744
sh>
```

Your `/bin/sh` may vary, but this appears to be the appropriate behaviour:

- supplying a filename argument to /bin/sh will interpret it as the filename of a shell script and try to execute it
- supplying -c with an argument will interpret that argument as a /bin/sh command line and try to execute that

For more details, type

```
man sh
```